# How do I start the cron daemon in my docker container?

Tags: linux, cron, docker

I am trying to start a cron daemon in my docker container runtime using systemctl. I run docker build and then when I try to run systemctl start crond.service in my startup script, I get the following error: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down. I am using CBL-Mariner and I made sure to install systemd.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/cbl-mariner/base/core:2.0

ENV NFDUMP_VERSION 1.6.18
ENV NFDUMP_RELEASE v${NFDUMP_VERSION}.tar.gz

# Health Probe
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
# sFlow
EXPOSE 6343/udp

RUN tdnf update && tdnf install -y \
    autoconf \
    byacc \
    cronie \
    flex \
    bzip2-devel \
    rrdtool-devel \
    libtool \
    make \
    nmap-ncat \
    pkgconf \
    wget \ 
    curl \
    jq \
    tar \
    automake \
    gcc \
    binutils \
    glibc-devel \
    kernel-headers \
    awk \
    azcopy \
    systemd 
    
# Install nfdump/sfcapd
WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN wget https://github.com/phaag/nfdump/archive/${NFDUMP_RELEASE} --no-check-certificate \
    && tar xvfz ${NFDUMP_RELEASE} \
    && cd nfdump-${NFDUMP_VERSION} \
    && ./autogen.sh \
    && ./configure --enable-sflow \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && ldconfig
RUN rm -fr /usr/local/src/*

ENV PATH "$PATH:/root"
WORKDIR /root
COPY cron_nfdump_combined.sh cron_nfdump_combined.sh
COPY nfdump_combined.sh nfdump_combined.sh
COPY startup.sh startup.sh

RUN chmod +x startup.sh
RUN chmod +x cron_nfdump_combined.sh
RUN chmod +x nfdump_combined.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "startup.sh"]
```

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "startup.sh"]`: not started with systemd as the error tells. You have an XY problem. I guess you don't have to use systemd to start cron, but you have to understand how a daemon works and is started. Eg: as in the "old days" with sysv init scripts. Beside, you might not need cron at all but it's also in the X of the XY problem: why cron?

Comment: I need to run a script in a scheduled manner (every 5 minutes at the 0th and 5th minutes), how else can I do this?

Comment: And this would be indefinitely

Comment: Put a loop in your script that sleeps for the desired amount of time.

Comment: I understand I can do that, but how would I make sure it runs at only the 0th and 5th minutes time wise.